# Getting Firebase Page Not Found issues even when the index.html is found

Tags: json, firebase-hosting

I am using Firebase hosting to deploy an application. The index.html file is in the root directory and the firebase.json is in the standard format.

```js
{
  "firebase": "memorytext",
  "public": ".",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

Even though the deployment process in the node command prompt works smoothly (without warning that there is no index.html file), once I open I consistently see the Page Not Found error.

Can anyone instruct me on how to resolve this issue?